# how do i get the current logged in users in cakephp cakedc users

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0, cakedc

please, can some one tell me how to get the current logged in user in CAKEDC users plugin in cake php. i want to be able to use it at will within the application. just as wordpress' : loggedin_user(), get_current_user().

Answer (score 1):

generally once a user goes through Auth in CakePHP, the way to get the user is $this->Auth->user(); Go ahead and try that in the controller ;).